# Form with dynamic id & name fields

Tags: java, html, handler

I have a form that looks like this :
cat1 [int field]
cat2 [int field]
cat3 [int field]

The fact is that my categories are different each time.
How do i Handle this in my handler ?

Dont know how i should set my getter/setter

Heres my jsp :

```
    <jsp:useBean id="formHandler" scope="page" class="com.pipo.EditStatusMappingHandler"><%--
--%><jsp:setProperty name="formHandler" property="*" /><%--
--%></jsp:useBean>

<form action="jsp/form/mapStatus.jsp" method="POST" name='categoryForm'>     
        <ul>
        <foreach collection="<%= categorySet %>" type="Category" name="itCategory" >
           <li>
            <label for="<%= itCategory.getId() %>"><%= itCategory.getName(userLang) %></label>
            <input type="text" name="<%= itCategory.getId() %>" id="<%= itCategory.getId() %>"/>    
           </li>
        </foreach>
        </ul>
          <div class="modal-buttons buttons">
            <input style="text-align:right;" class='formButton mainButton'  type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

I dont know what to put in my handler to get the input name = <%= itCategory.getId() %>

Comment: Can you give an example of your code in Java? I am sure there is a simple answer. ;)

Comment: Well the thing is that I dont know how to code it in Java. 
My categories fields can be different so I dont know what should I type in my handler's getter&setter

Comment: Have you considered using a `Map<String, Data>` which is keyed by any String?

Comment: How do I code my getters/setters with a Map of string ? And what are the name of my fields in my form with this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `Map<String, Data>` the getters and setters are defined for you.

```
Map<String, Data> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Data>();
// set values.
map.put("field1", data1);
map.put("field2", data2);
// get values.
Data dataA = map.get("field1");
Data dataB = map.get("field2");
```

Comment: Where shoud I use this ? Handler or directly in my jsp ?

Comment: Wherever you need it. ;) Possibly in both.

Comment: The thing is that i dont know the names of my fields since they are dynamic

Comment: Something has to know the names of the fields, is it in a class, a configuration file, the form, is it user entered?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use reflection on the form object to get to know the category fields and invoke the corresponding operation.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Java web frameworks support mapped properties (i.e. `getCategoryValue(String categoryName)` / `setCategoryValue(String categoryName, Integer value)`) or direct read-write access to a map inside the form bean/action bean.

Without knowing the framework you're using and what you mean by "handler", it's difficult to give a more precise answer."